# SQL Server 2005 UDF to make a table data-type of self referencing table data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursion, user-defined-types

I have a typical self-referencing table of employees.

How can you build an UDF to return a table data-type that can be used in other queries to join to such that I pass the UDF a `id` of a user in the table and get a result of that user's `id` and all users linked to him via a `managerId`?

The table I have is `EmployeeId, ManagerID, Name`....

All I need is to pass an `EmployeeId` and get a recursive result of all records who's `ManagerID` is the id of the passed in param, and any of the records that have these as managers, and so on...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetEmployees  
(  
  @EmployeeId int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
  WITH yourcte AS
  (
    SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, Name
    FROM Employees
    WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerID, e.Name
    FROM Employees e
    JOIN yourcte y ON e.ManagerID = y.EmployeeId
  )
SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, Name
FROM yourcte
)
```